Server-side events (SSE) when using flask via google webapp
I have hnuted an answer on this and closest I have come to my issue is this old and unanswered post here:  python flask + Server Sent Events(SSE) in Google App Engine(GAE)
I have a web app built in python flask and I want to push SSE tot he client.  When i run this locally it works but when i deploy and run on google I dont get the events; everything else works but no events come back in to the client.
also when I run local, using browser debug tool i can see the stream data comin gin every 0,2 seconds which I do not see when deployed to google... so im getting the feeling google web app does not support this? but I cannot confirm this one way or another.
Any help on this would be massive...thanks
current = {"name":""}



def generate_stream_data():

  while True:
    
    # Simulate data generation
    data = current
    
    yield f"data:{json.dumps(data)}\n\n"
    
    time.sleep(0.2)



@app.route('/log_training', methods = ['POST'])                          
def log_training():

    payload = request.get_json()

    for item in payload:

        current["name"] = item
    


@app.route('/stream')
def log_stream():

    return Response(generate_stream_data(), mimetype='text/event-stream')


AFAIK, App Engine does not support streaming connection (websocket, SSE, and other). Use Cloud Run instead
